# Can dependabot notify users if it can not update the dependencies, i.e. it can't parse the module file?

Tags: github, dependabot, github-dependabot

Due to some miss configuration dependabot wasn't able to parse our modules file. This wasn't noticed for quite some time, since there was no notification on that and you have to actively visit the dependency insight in github to see the problem. Can I configure dependabot so that it will notify me on problems with updates in the future?